# Dynamic value in popup

Tags: php, jquery

PHP Code:

```
$cour = mysql_sql('SELECT c.id, c.category, cc.name, c.fullname,c.summary FROM 
                   mdl_course c, mdl_course_categories cc WHERE c.id = cc.course');

echo '<table>'; 
foreach($cour as $cou) 
{
   $coursename = $cou->fullname;
   $courseid = $cou->id;
   $summary = $cou->summary;
   echo '
    <tr style="border:1px solid #BACC82;">  
        <td><a onclick="ShowHide(); return false;">'.$coursename.'</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--SHOW AND HIDE DIV-->
    <div id="enclosure" style="display:none;">'.$summary.'</div>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Javascript code:

```
function ShowHide(id) {
    $('#enclosure_'+ id).animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
}
```

This was working as you guys suggested on Stackoverflow, but I need in the same manner as a small popup (with smooth) in jQuery. Now the summary informaion should display in a popup
Could anyone help me?

Comment: as written in your code the div also be generated with each row with the repeated id, but id should be unique for each element so use class instead id for the div and apply the popup script for that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/*
Did you think of Ajax ?

```
function ShowHide(id) {
  $.get("page.php", 'id='+id, function(data){
     $('#enclosure_'+ id).animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
  });
}
```

I didn't test my code, but adapt it as needed...
*/

Edit :

Oups I made a mistake I didn't read well enough your question.

on your php side you have :

```
<div id="enclosure" style="display:none;">'.$summary.'</div>';
```

You need to do id="enclosure_'.$cou->id.'"

Comment: I didn't use popup, but I am showing summary down when i click